# Firebase Data message not handled by FirebaseMessagingService when app is in Doze mode

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am sending "Data" messages with Firebase to my app, but when the app is in Doze mode, those messages are not handled by FirebaseMessagingService, even when my app is whitelisted for battery optimisation and my messages marked as priority.

[Firebase docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/receive) on why I choose "Data" messages instead of notification.

[Android mechanism](https://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/doze-standby) to add app to whitelist and skip battery optimisation.

[Firebase priority messages](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options) according to documentation.

I follow all this steps, and even after this, messages are not handed to my implementation of FirebaseMessagingService.

Any idea how to force messages be handed by FirebaseMessagingService, even in Doze mode?

Note: I'm working on a VoIp app, if message its not immediately handed, its no longer valid and the purpose of it is lost.

Comment: After a while we found out the problem. In server side instead of implementing the newest API the legacy one was implemented.

They have a different payload that can be seen here:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/http-server-ref#notification-payload-support

basically instead of :

`"android":{ "ttl": "0s", "priority": "high" }`

we had to use:

`"priority": 10, "time_to_live": 0`

Comment: as read doc the time_to_leave mean the max time to receiver fcm notification, why set it to 0?

Comment: Hi, according to documentation [Firebase TTL](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options#ttl) 

Another advantage of specifying the lifespan of a message is that FCM never throttles messages with a time-to-live value of 0 seconds. In other words, FCM guarantees best effort for messages that must be delivered "now or never." Keep in mind that a time_to_live value of 0 means messages that can't be delivered immediately are discarded. However, because such messages are never stored, this provides the best latency for sending notification messages.

Answer (score 0):

If you are following all the documentation, it may still be the case that FCM has deprioritized your messages, as described in the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options#setting-the-priority-of-a-message):

> High priority messages generally should result in user interaction
>   with your app or its notifications. If FCM detects a pattern in which
>   they don't, your messages may be de-prioritized. Android P introduced
>   app standby buckets which limit the number of FCM high priority
>   messages you can send to your app that don't result in the user using
>   your app or viewing a notification. If, in response to a high priority
>   message, a notification is displayed in a way that is visible to the
>   user, then your app standby bucket quota will not be consumed by that
>   message.

There is no "force" mode that lets you operate above the rules stated in the documentation.  If anyone could simply bypass the rules, then everyone would do it, and the rules would become useless to the end user, who is just trying to save their battery from apps that aren't following best practices.

Comment: Hi, thx for feedback. 
I got your point, rules must be followed, what I think I am doing in this case. 
As a VoIP app, it fits in the requirements to be added to whitelist. Also we are not consuming extra battery because app is not running in background, we use firebase to trigger the app when is necessary. 

Also I can assume that messages are not being deprioritized because when in background, without doze mode, they are received immediately. 

When I run: "adb shell dumpsys deviceidle unforce" messages are delivered immediately. Looks like a bug or excess of control.

Answer (score 0):

After a while we found out the problem.

In server side instead of implementing the newest API the legacy one was implemented.

They have a different payload that can be seen here: [Firebase Payload](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/http-server-ref#notification-payload-support)

basically instead of :

```
"android":{
    "ttl": "0s", 
    "priority": "high"
}
```

we had to use:

```
"priority": 10,
"time_to_live": 0
```